# Reg a facebook interview ques

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

"http://learn.hackerearth.com/question/400/facebook-programming-challenge-bar-problem-n-friends-are-playing-a-game/#c3089"

For the question in the mentioned url I did a sample program with the sample input given and got a different solution from the one mentioned viz. {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} .
What is the problem with this brute force approach? I just want to correct my understanding of the given problem.

```
a=[2,5,3]
b=[8,1,6]
c=[7,4,9]
outList=[]
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        for k in c:
            outList.append(sorted([i,j,k])[0])
            print i,j,k,sorted([i,j,k])[0]
print "List of numbers"
print sorted(set(outList))

Output
------
2 8 7 2
2 8 4 2
2 8 9 2
2 1 7 1
2 1 4 1
2 1 9 1
2 6 7 2
2 6 4 2
2 6 9 2
5 8 7 5
5 8 4 4
5 8 9 5
5 1 7 1
5 1 4 1
5 1 9 1
5 6 7 5
5 6 4 4
5 6 9 5
3 8 7 3
3 8 4 3
3 8 9 3
3 1 7 1
3 1 4 1
3 1 9 1
3 6 7 3
3 6 4 3
3 6 9 3
List of numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem description in the linked problem is wrong. It says "the third biggest" but the example uses "the third smallest".

Your solution seems fine.

Comment: So which interpretion do you think is correct. Given this is a facebok problem..

Comment: The correct way to solve the interview question is first to point out the error and ask for clarification, and then solve the problem using the updated problem description. If you have to write the code before you can get a clarification, make an assumtpion, insert a code comment describing the issue and how to change the code if the assumption is wrong.

Comment: I think your interpretation of the text is correct. However, it is impossible to say if the mistake is in the text or in the example; therefore it is crucial to ask for clarification. After all, fulfilling the specification is pointless if the specification is wrong.